# Checking availability of Enterprise(a.k.a. E3) license in powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Need your help with getting a table of ad accounts, in which accounts which have E3 license will be marked as "True" and "False" for those who dont have it.

So my command set is as below:

```
 Get-ADUser  -Filter 'Name -like "NK*"' -properties PasswordLastSet, Enabled  | sort Name | ft Name, PasswordLastSet, Enabled
```

What command should i input to alsto get a row for E3 license availability?

```
 Get-ADUser  -Filter 'Name -like "NK*"' -properties PasswordLastSet, Enabled  | sort Name | ft Name, PasswordLastSet, Enabled
```

Comment: Do you have any property to reflect if a user has the license or not in your AD? If not, you should consider do an Azure AD/Microsoft Graph query to get what are you asking, as the license info is inherent to O365 and not AD. More information [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/view-licensed-and-unlicensed-users-with-microsoft-365-powershell?view=o365-worldwide).